# view（jsp）を返さないレスポンスのあるControllerクラスの実装方法

Tags: java, spring

Javaではない外部アプリから呼び出され、ダウンロードファイルを返すControllerクラスの実装方法について教えてください。
以下のURLにアクセスすると、呼び出し元画面上にダウンロードダイアログを開きます。
Springでjspを返さずに、ダウンロードファイルだけを返すメソッド場合、以下の実装方法だとreturnが空になってしまいます。
正しい実装方法を教えてください。

```
@Controller
public class downloadController {
    @RequestMapping(path="/download", method="GET")
    public String download(@RequestParam param, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        // 何かの処理
        res.setContentType("application/octed-stream");
        res.Header("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), res.getOutputStream());
        return "";
    }
}
```

構成：動的プロジェクト
Spring：5.3.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ダウンロードファイルを返す`View`(`AbstractView`)クラスを実装して、`Controller`クラスでは、そのView名をreturnするように実装すると良いと思います。(`Controller`で実装している内容を`View`に移すイメージ)

実装イメージ(View)

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView;
// 他のimportは省略

@Component
public class DownloadView extends AbstractView {
    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(
        Map<String, Object> model,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        String fileName = (String) model.get("fileName");

        response.setContentType("application/octed-stream");
        response.Header("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)), response.getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

実装イメージ(Controller)

```
@Controller
public class downloadController {
    @RequestMapping(path="/download", method="GET")
    public String download(@RequestParam param, HttpServletResponse res, Model model) throws Exception {
        // 何かの処理

        // ダウンロードするファイル名を設定する
        model.addAttribute("fileName", param.getFilename());
        return "downloadView";
    }
}
```

Comment: AbstractViewクラスのAPIを確認し、実装方法も確認しました。この方法で実現できました。